# R: loop over all variables and display a frequency table for each

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame and I need to display a frequency table for each variable. The following code does not work (no error message but no tables printed) and I can't find the solution despite extensive searching. I would be grateful for pointers.

```
varlist <- names(df)
for (var in varlist) {
   mytable <- table(paste("df$", var, sep = ""))
   mytable
}
```

I am not working on my machine so I would prefer to stick to base R if possible, to avoid installing packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as categorical variables are of factor data type, `summary(df)` will give you frequency tables for each of them.

Alternatively, you can use `lapply` to loop `table` over the columns: `lapply(df[names(df)], table))`

Comment: Thanks Andrea! These two worked. Any ideas why my original code did not work?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure - one reason is that you need `paste()` instead of `print()` within `table()`, but then there's something else... In general, I've always been encouraged not to use for loops in R when repeating a function over variables. That for loop would work fine in Stata, though. (Could you mark my answer as "accepted", please? :)

Comment: My bad Andrea, it was originally 'paste' not 'print', I've edited it now.